# The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup. markup

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
      document.write(script src=\/feeds/posts/default/?max-results=+numposts4+&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=owlcontent;\><\/script>);
</script>
```

I'm getting error from above code someone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I guess you have to pass string to `document.write()`, and also use `appendChild()` instead of it. I mean, you are trying to do this:

```
document.write("<script src=\/feeds/posts/default/?max-results=+numposts4+&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=owlcontent;\><\/script>");
```

but instead, you can do this (better practise):

```
let scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src = "path/to/your/script.js";
document.body.appendChild(scriptTag);
```